# How an ethereum contract store its variables in blockchains?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, contract-debugging, storage

I would like to view variables of contract at each point-in-time.How an ethereum contract store its variables in blockchains and how can i parse  blockchains to explor contract and its variables?